# Error with Rails / sqlite3 deployment to heroku postgresql -- have already updated gemfile and master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am on a first time deploy from a local Rails environment with SQLite3 to Heroku with postgresql.  I have already updated my gemfile to make the appropriate development/production group clauses.  And I made sure to include those changes in the master.  However, I repeatedly get the following error when I run the db:push

Would greatly appreciate the help

```
prompt> C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require': LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Seque
l::AdapterNotFound)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/r
ubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/r
ubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/r
ubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `block in tsk_require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/s
equel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/sche
ma.rb:17:in `dump_table'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/bin/schema:32
:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `heroku db:push` command to work, you will need to install both `taps` and `sqlite3` gems inside the version of Ruby Heroku bundles with it.

From the above backtrace, seems `taps` is installed, but is missing `sqlite3` adapter.

To install it, please try the following:

- Start an elevated command prompt (so you can write into `Program Files` without issues
- `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin"` directory.
- Invoke `gem install sqlite3 --no-ri --no-rdoc`

That should install the missing gem and allow `heroku db:push` to work with your sqlite3 database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course, I am now focused on solving another issue -- taps server error / time zone displacement

Comment: That is caused by running sqlite3 locally and using postgres in the remote. You can solve that by installing taps in your ruby installation, running it as server against the local sqlite database and then use `heroku db:pulll <taps-server-url>` that will tell taps to use the taps version of the database and push that to heroku. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the idea (as I have been spinning my wheels looking through other forum posts on the topic).  I have taps installed.  And I can start it.  Two questions -- how do I make sure the local sqlite db is running on it and what is the approx. url for the taps db on my machine?  I really appreciate it

Comment: You use taps server to run a local taps server of your sqlite database, then you use that to push to your remote heroku pg database. See here: https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/93#issuecomment-10647418 and see the help of `heroku db:push` for that is `DATABASE_URL` (hint: is your source/local one, which in this case will be your local taps server)

Comment: So @Luis my local db url is in the format 'localdbuser:localdbpass@localhost/dbname'?  I can't seem to find this kind of info anywhere.  (I found my remote/heroku db url on heroku.com.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Luis (I realize these are simple, rookie questions!)

Comment: Please don't use sqlite3 locally and postgres remotely. You will have a bad time. You should have parity between your environments